# Restore HTC One X to original ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, htc-one-x, stock-rom

My HTC One X came with ICS pre-installed, but then I upgraded it to Android 4.2.2 using CyanogenMod. Now I want to reset my phone to its original ROM, but couldn't find a way to do it.

Someone suggested that I download and run:

> RUU_ENDEAVOR_U_ICS_40_Vodafone_UK_1.26.161.2_Radio_1.1204.90.13_release_251227_signed

but it didn't work. When I run the .exe I get the error:

```
 Error[155]: UKNOWN ERROR
```

My bootloader shows its version as:

```
version-main: 3.14.161.27 
(bootloader) DEBUG: cid: VODAP001
ENDEAVORU PUT SHIP S-ON RL
*** UNLOCKED ***
```

How can I get the stock ROM reinstalled?

Comment: Where did you run the `.exe` file? If directly on the Android device, this would explain the error. It's most likely a Windows executable / self-extracting archive.

Answer (score 5):

This is a protection that HTC uses to ensure quality in their devices. To re-install their custom stock, you must re-lock your phone. To do this, place your phone into fast-boot mode and plugin in via USB:

At the command line (or wherever you may have the fastboot binary), execute these commands:

> fastboot devices
>   fastboot oem lock

This will lock your bootloader and allow you to run the RUU. Your device should now report "LOCKED". After your device is locked, proceed with running your *.exe on Windows.

(Make sure you're installing the right one first!)
List of RUU's: http://androidfiles.org/ruu/?developer=Endeavor

Full Tutorial: http://androidforums.com/one-s-all-things-root/691874-guide-how-run-ruu-your-htc-one-s.html